# ms access updating field conditionally on form.activate

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

My question concerns situations where custom code is required to auto-increment fields in MS Access, specifically with issues that arise from using such code in the OnActivate event.

I have a field [Group_ID] that auto-increments each time a new record is made using custom code in the OnCurrent and OnActivate events. Sometimes I need Group_ID to be incremented OnActivate, but sometimes I do not. In some cases users will actually use a "duplicate record" button to use the same Group_ID (along with most other fields) for a subsequent record. In situations like these, I'd like to set a condition for the OnActivate event that allows users to reference other forms or tables without re-querying Group_ID upon returning to the form to finish a record. Here is my code:

```
'increments Group_ID when a new record is made

Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Me.NewRecord = True Then
        Me.Group_ID = Nz(DMax("Group_ID", "All_sightings"), 1) + 1
    End If
End Sub

'increments Group_ID when the form becomes active IF the value is no
longer max value + 1

Private Sub Form_Activate()
If Me.Group_ID = Nz(DMax("Group_ID", "All_sightings")) + 1 Then
    Else
        Me.Requery
End If
End Sub
```

What I would like to do is add an additional condition to the Form_Activate sub that checks whether a different field is already filled out (e.g. if the "duplicate" button was used) when the form re-activates after a user returns to a partially completed record. This field will not require any input from the user because it will be automatically filled when a user clicks the duplicate button. The field I have chosen is [UTM_x].

I have tried:

```
=IIF(Me.Group_ID = Nz(DMax("Group_ID", "All_sightings")) + 1 And Not IsNull(Me.UTM_x), "", Me.Requery)
```

And various other combinations of nested IIF() and IfThenElse statements, but have not had any luck. The form continues to requery every time on the OnActivate event when Group_ID is not more than (max+1). Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you step debugged? Why would you need the Activate event?

Comment: @June7 As written, there's no bug; I think I need to add code to create more restrictive conditions on which the activate event increments Group_ID, but I'm not sure how to tackle this. I've shared the strategy I have tried, and am asking whether the strategy/code is flawed. The activate event is important b/c there are two separate forms that allow users to add records to the table containing Group_ID. Code in OnActivate keeps Group_ID fresh when returning to either form; however, I don't want it to do this when a record has been duplicated (multiple records in same group) and isn't finished

Comment: Step debug, see the values of variables and controls as the code processes. Are they what you expect? Apparently it is flawed if you don't get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with iif statements and more if-then-else statements, eventually finding a solution to my problem. Here it is:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
If Me.Group_ID = Nz(DMax("Group_ID", "All_sightings")) + 1 Then
'blank/do nothing because Group_ID is already max+1
    ElseIf IsNull(UTM_x) Then
        Me.Requery 'makes Group_ID max+1 because null UTM_x means it's a new record
        Else
            'blank/do nothing because Group_ID = max and this is a duplicated record
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: As june pointed out, your code is strange.  Why should a `Requery` create a new `Group_Id` unless there is not saved data? you are aware that a `Requery` can be executed by a ribbon-button or F5-Key, won't that cause wrong data? The `Group_id` can be set as a default value, that is depending on the "duplicate" button.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "unless there is not saved data." I use form.activate b/c I want to automate the requery. The user should not have to do this. Group_ID must be requeried b/c the Group_ID is auto-assigned in a new record regardless of whether the record is completed. This means an already assigned Group_ID could get used by a separate form. To prevent this, I am having the form requery if it is blank upon form.activate and the Group_ID is no longer max+1. I get that this is odd, but I have not gotten the impression that you or @June7 understood my question. That's my bad.

Comment: We are getting closer ;) I think problem is your misuse of the auto-increment. Usually you use it to get an easy ptimary key (PK) that needs to be unique. Your field is not a PK and has no unique index, that can cause unwanted duplicates. Is there any other purpose for Group_ID  than marking records as subsequent ?

Comment: haha thanks for sticking with me here. Yes, I realize it is an unconventional use, but it does have a purpose. Also, I want to clarify that I am not using the data type "autonumber" for Group_ID. I already have a PK that is "autonumber." Group_ID is a way of tying sets of records together. I need it to automatically generate a new Group_ID when a record represents an individual from a new group, but I need to automatically keep Group_ID the same as the last record when the subsequent record represents an individual that belongs to the same group as the primary record. The code above does this.

Comment: *i said primary but i meant previous